# Populating Listview from ArrayList which in turn is populated by .txt file

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

i am working on this Android application  which firstly downloads a .txt file from internet then populates the arraylist and in the end listview. The problem is that the Listview doesn't seem to populate despite that my file  downloading and reading  is everything ok since i have tested it with a TOAST.

Here is my code

Downloading File and Reading with  AsyncTask

```
    public class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        String filenamelist=TEST_FILE_NAME;
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


           //Here i download the file

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
return "Executed";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            try {
                InputStream instream = new FileInputStream(new File(getCacheDir(), filenamelist));
                InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(instream);
                BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);
                String key,value = null;

                do{
                    key = bReader.readLine();
                    if(key != null)
                        value = bReader.readLine();
//channelname is the ArrayList                    
channelname.add(key);
                    channelmaps.put(key,value);




                } while (key != null && value != null);




            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    }
```

Declaration of ArrayList

```
 ArrayList<String> channelname = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Listview

```
 final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    channelname.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));

    ChannelAdapter cAdapter = new ChannelAdapter(this, channelname);
    listView.setAdapter(cAdapter);
```

ChannelAdapter class

```
private class ChannelAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
    {
        ArrayList<String> channelname;
        public ChannelAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> channelname)
        {
            super  (context, R.layout.activity_list_channels, channelname);
            this.channelname = channelname;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            try
            {
                if(convertView==null)
                {
                    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylistchannel,parent, false);
                }
                String  name = getItem(position);
                TextView txtview = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Channelname);
                txtview.setText(name);
                return convertView;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount()
        {
            return channelname.size();
        }

        @Override
        public String getItem(int position)
        {
            return channelname.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

So what's the problem with my code?  Why isn't the listview populated?

Answer (score 0):

You should do

```
cAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

after the cycle in which you've read all the items from the file;

Comment: It's still the  same. The listview is not populated.